# Is it possible make tmux status bar float over the terminal content (instead of push it)?

Tags: tmux

I recently changed my tmux config to toggle the status bar when I press a key map.

When the status bar is displayed, it pushes the terminal content up and the flick effect is annoying.
Is it possible to display the status bar over the terminal content?
(tmux prompt have this 'floating behavior', so I was thinking if there is some option to also apply it to status bar)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround!
Instead of displaying the status, I'm using a `display-message` and recreating my status line inside the message. The `display-message` have the wanted float behavior.

Something like

```
tmux display-message -d 3000 "#{E:status-format[0]}"
```

[image]